# middle mouse button copy and paste in io.elementary.terminal

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-terminal, elementary-project, xorg

Description:    elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera middle mouse button copy and paste not working as expected

Being a *nix user since the 80s, I'm kind of attached to middle mouse button copy and paste working in the terminal. Is this something I can enable in io.elementary.terminal?

xterm middle mouse button copy and paste works as expected, for example.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Click has the option you're searching for.

[image]